# Swear on Allah's name

Tags: forgiveness, tawba, oaths

With a heavy heart and guilt i am writing this
My friend asked me if you ever commited this sin which i had but i have repented
I said no
He pushed me to say "wallah"
First i said "yea just trust me"
But then he kept saying that say it
I then to escape from the situation said it and immediately felt very very bad
He also said if u lied you will not get a certain thing(which is very dear to me) but i had lied by then and also swore on Allah's name

What do i have to do to repent?
Do i have to feed 10 people?
Will Allah not provide me with the thing i hold very dear due to this?

JazakAllah

Comment: I am not acquainted with Arabic, but I guess what you ask about, you have not only committed an (unnamed) sin but did also a false oath about it?

Comment: In historical Christianity, there was something called Indulgenz, a fee of money to be payed to be forgiven of sins. There were thirty years of bitter civil war about. You cannot be freed of a sin whatever you do if you do not regret it.

Comment: Yes i had repented on the sin i committed which is in the past but my friend asked generally .....like *hey have you ever done this?"  I said no but he pushed me to take oath and I just made the mistake which i regret

Comment: I have no solid understanding of Islam, and as no one else has even left a comment, I guess this is probably because your case cannot be answered in general terms ("asking for personal advice"). A christian would ask a priest for advice, and I' sure in Islam there are also persons of trust you can ask for your special case.